# How can I write a txt file with multiple delimiters [R]?

Tags: r

I'm trying to write a txt file that has multiple delimiters:

```
text|||value_1|value_2||||
```

Currently, I've tried:

```
write.table(variable, "file.txt", sep = "|", quote = FALSE, row.names = FALSE)
```

But I'm not sure how to use multiple delimiters given that sep only takes in 1 argument. Will appreciate any help! Thank you!

Comment: May we ask why you want to do this in the first place?  Keep in mind, that on the other end, namely reading this file back into R or some other tool, you will face the same problem of how to handle multiple delimiters.

Comment: Hi, I'm just using R to write a txt file in that manner so that I can feed it into some test code in Java. I'm just trying to match the txt file to the one that's currently used for the Java test code, so I won't be reading it back into R;

Comment: pad with NA columns and use `na = ''`: `write.table(cbind('text', NA, NA, 'value_1', 'value_2', NA, NA, NA, NA), sep = '|', na = '')`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can write using one delimiter, read it back, and replace the one delimiter with whatever you want before writing again

```
write.table(mtcars, "tmp.txt", sep = "|", quote = FALSE)
d = readLines("tmp.txt")
d = gsub("|", "|||", d, fixed = TRUE)
writeLines(d, "tmp2.txt")
```